# Combine two image collections into one Image collection Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am very new to GEE and I'm even having difficulties deciphering other people's potential solutions.

After processing each data source into one imageCollection each, I am trying to make a simple calculation between these two. One of the ideas that I had is to combine both imageCollections into one image collection where each image have bands from imageCollection1 and imageCollection2.
I tried the solution in the link, and while the join is successful, it doesn't seem to be able to add the second band. Is it because the metadata of the two imageCollections are different ?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c0bb0bbdccf975d144b52031321795b6

```
var GRACE = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GRACE/MASS_GRIDS/LAND')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2003-08-01', '2003-12-01')).select('lwe_thickness_csr');

print(GRACE, 'GRACE')

var SWS = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/FLDAS/NOAH01/C/GL/M/V001');
SWS = SWS.filterDate('2003-08-01', '2003-12-01').select('SoilMoi100_200cm_tavg');


/// Get information about the GRACE projection.
var graceProjection = GRACE.first().projection();

///Resampling to meet GRACE resolution
var resampleSWS = SWS.map(function(image) {
    var mean = image
      // Force the next reprojection to aggregate instead of resampling.
     .reduceResolution({
        reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
       maxPixels: 1024
     }).rename('resampled SWS')
     // Request the data at the scale and projection of the GRACE image.
      .reproject({
       crs: graceProjection
     });
      return mean.set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'))
})

print(resampleSWS, 'resampled SWS')


///Combine two image collections
var mod1 = GRACE.select('lwe_thickness_csr')
var mod2 = resampleSWS.select('resampled SWS')

var filter = ee.Filter.equals({
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
});

// Create the join.
var simpleJoin = ee.Join.simple();

// Applt join
var mod1join = ee.ImageCollection(simpleJoin.apply(mod1, mod2, filter))
var mod2join = ee.ImageCollection(simpleJoin.apply(mod2, mod1, filter))

print('Joined', mod1join, mod2join)
```

I don't see to be able to get this running right. Any suggestions?

Comment: add the code to the question so it can be reopened

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the solution you're looking for is an inner join. It's described [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/joins_inner)

```js
///Combine two image collections
var mod1 = GRACE.select('lwe_thickness_csr')
var mod2 = resampleSWS.select('resampled SWS')

var filter = ee.Filter.equals({
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
});

// Create the join.
var simpleJoin = ee.Join.inner();

// Inner join
var innerJoin = ee.ImageCollection(simpleJoin.apply(mod1, mod2, filter))

var joined = innerJoin.map(function(feature) {
  return ee.Image.cat(feature.get('primary'), feature.get('secondary'));
})

print('Joined', joined)
```

Comment: Indeed it worked perfectly. The fact that it matches between all the elements saved me so much time as it also joins the  images with the same timestamp.

Thank you so much!

Comment: If you can, modify the question and add the code to it.

Comment: Does this solution work for image collections from different sensors (eg, Landsat 8 and MODIS?) and does the join happens based on the spatial extent or only the time stamp?